# Export mesh from blender to matlab

Tags: vertices, edges, faces

I have already generated a model in Solidworks. I want to generate and export mesh of the model i.e., edges, vertex, faces etc. I can import my model into blender but I do not know how to generate mesh and extract edges, vertices and faces data. I want to read mesh data (edges, vertices and faces) in matlab.
Please anyone helps me, it will be appreciated.
[image]
Thanks
Adil

Comment: What do you use or want to use in matlab to load the model? This will determine what file format you need.

Comment: Looks like Matlab has STL addons:
https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22409-stl-file-reader